# How can i debug API project created using C#

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-apicontroller

I want to debug my C# API project, which is currently in my local.

The reason for debugging is that the function below in that API project returns `null` for a particular JSON.

```
[Route("api/NMRController/Disposition")]
[HttpPost]
public NMR_Object Disposition(NMR nmr)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"nmr: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nmr)}");
        string CorrectiveAction = nmr.CorrectiveAction;
        string DispositionResult = nmr.DispositionResult;
        string DispositionComment = nmr.DispositionComment;
        string NoteForGroup = nmr.NoteForGroup;
        string SerialNo = nmr.SerialNo;

        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr_nmr"].ConnectionString;

        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand myCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
        myCommand.Connection = conn;
        if (conn.State.ToString() != "Open")
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE NMR_SerialNo SET CorrectiveAction = @CorrectiveAction, DispositionResult = @DispositionResult, DispositionComment = @DispositionComment, NoteForGroup = @NoteForGroup WHERE SerialNo = @SerialNo";
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorrectiveAction", CorrectiveAction);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DispositionResult", DispositionResult);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DispositionComment", DispositionComment);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoteForGroup", NoteForGroup);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNo", SerialNo);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        // write insert query

        var RM = new NMR_Object();
        RM.data = "";
        RM.success = true;
        // RM = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt));
        
        return RM;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var RME = new NMR_Object();
        RME.success = false;
        RME.message = "NMR POST: " + ex.Message;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is the JSON that I have passed during the post call:

```
{
  "CorrectiveAction": "testing",
  "DispositionResult": "testing",
  "DispositionComment": "testing",
  "NoteForGroup": "testing",
  "SerialNo": "MYSQL"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Visual Studio for Mac, open your Project.

On the upper left hand side you can choose whether you want to use http or https, then you need to choose debug, and the browser with which you wish to debug.

Then click run

After your project successfully builds and is up and running, you can place breakpoints in visual studio by clicking on the line name next to the line of code you want to test.

Visual studio will break when the breakpoint is entered and you can watch your variables

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to debug your API if you run it from visual studio. You can just place a breakpoint in your method that is triggered whenever a request to it is made. You can make a request using a webbrowser or postman. From there you should be able to step thru the code, inspect variables, etc.

This should at least be true for a default asp.Net project. If you made customizations to how the project is run you might need to do other things to allow debugging.

If the breakpoint is not triggered at all there might be some issue with your routing. It might be useful to create a default project just to verify that your test setup works.